# Spoof Android/iOS App and Replicate API Request

Tags: android, ios, wireshark, spoofing

Im wondering if it is possible to run app like instagram on an android simulator, logged in using your own account, use wireshark or other tool to spoof the request it is making to get the feeds, obtain any required auth / api keys, and then build exact similar request to obtain the same data like instagram app?

Comment: Did you try doing this? Your question is vague, what exactly are you asking?

Comment: I want to know if it's possible or if anyone has done this before